# Is there any way to discover what's being dispatched to?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, vaadin

Sometimes in our code base, I have no idea which classes are being called when I do something. My solution to this is to ask someone where the code lives, however I suspect there is a way for me to discover which of our classes are being executed when I click a button. How might I become self reliant and find out which classes/methods are being executed myself (presumably filtered so that I can ignore framework classes which I won't want to modify)?

I suspect I'm looking for something like a call stack, that only shows what happened after I set a certain point (e.g. I go to screen, click record stack, click button, view stack, kind of like chrome dev tools recording network requests, and compared to say wireshark recording of network requests, chrome is a more filtered view), and allows me to filter it. This is an educated guess though

Comment: Is this really Vaadin centric?

Comment: @cfrick probably not, I just tagged spring and vaadin to identify my stack. possibly not even idea or java centric, most likely just JVM. But just tagging jvm might imply that I know the answer. I really don't, could be involved in a tool I have, or a tool I don't.

Comment: In that case, this question is very vague.  Vaadin can help you with this (e.g. debug-mode, firebug/devconsole might give insight).  In spring you can ramp up the logging for more insight.  I fear this will attract lots of  well meant advice, but without a solid example, there will be no "right" answers.

Comment: @cfrick I would accept an answer specific to spring/vaadin I just don't know that an answer *would be* specific to those. If I knew a solution I wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit vague, but there are some general strategies for navigating unfamiliar code.

For example, when I'm trying trying to find what happens when a button is clicked, but I have no idea where the button is, the first place I begin is the button text. Search for the text. It's likely in a `.properties` (i.e. localization) file. Where's that property being used? Hopefully one of those places is the button.

Next, add a break point to the button's action. Click the button. Step through the code with the debugger. You can trace through the code without the debugger, but it's really easy to get side tracked.

Comment: this seems like it would work, when the button has a string, and when the property is literal rather "built". Sometimes the gettext property name is more dynamically constructed. Also sometimes said text could come from something like a database.

Comment: @xenoterracide The basic idea when working with unfamiliar code is to build off of whatever you know, no matter how little. You know it's a button labeled "Do Something". Grep for files containing "new Button(". Uh oh, grep found 200+ places, too many to look through each one. Search for files containing "new Button(" and "doSomething" (maybe the code is a variation of "Button doSomething = new Button"). Search returns 10, now we can manually look at each one.

Answer (score 1):

*Ok I bite for Vaadin, as it is the most specific out of the list and maybe the easiest to answer from a toplevel approach, which is the opposite of what @kuporific suggested.  So you can decide for yourself*

Given you are having a Vaadin application running from your IDE, beeing redirected to some start point of the app and now after some clicks are in the middle of some code, you want to debug.  You should have some IDE, that is able to navigate you quickly through code (e.g. find classes in the whole project, ctrl-click on methods, find implementations, ...).

Our example URL: `http://localhost:8080/sales/#!stats/2014`

Vaadin apps run on the container as servlets and are subclasses of `com.vaadin.ui.UI`.  In the url above `sales` is the context of the app. Go to the `UI` class and check the sublcasses.  There could be something like the `SalesUI` in your project -- there usually are not many descendants of this class.

Next note, that this URL ends on in `#!stats/2014`.  `#!` is used to manage views.  The first word (split by `/`) is the name of the view.  Views are implementing `com.vaadin.navigator.View` are added to the navigator instance.  So going for classes implementing this interface would be a good start.  Sane people name their classes sane, so most likely there would be a `SalesStatsView`.

Everything that renders in Vaadin is a Component of some sort.  So the view will build up it's content itself or delegate it to some helpers.  Use your browsers debug tools, to check the current content of the site.  Vaadin is quite verbose by setting CSS classes to the elements.  You will get a grip on the general layout quick (there are vertical/horizontal layouts, some major landmarks like a table or a chart, buttons, ...).  Take a mental note on containments and locations and try to find yourself a way through the code.

Views have an `enter` method, that can take care of further params.  In this case the `2014` in the URL is a param (everything after the first `/`.  So enter would deal with some loading regarding this variable.  Check for loading data specific to the view here.

As stated in the comments, this all is highly opinionated, and is a skill every developer has to learn and build up, but boils down maybe to something like this:

- Know the basic concepts, that are used compose applications and be able to navigate and investigate into concrete implementations (e.g. `Autowired` in spring: use the IDE to find concrete implementations and verify their actual use (breakpoint, logging, ...).
- Know the entry points of the technologies, that are used.  (e.g. `UI`, `View` in vaadin, `(Rest)Controller` in spring)
- Know the basic software patterns, especially, the ones you see used in your app.  (If there is a `SalesStatPresenter` class, a view is not far and expect to be in a world of the Model-View-Presenter-pattern).

How to get this knowledge?  Read the Vaadin book, read the spring core and web docs.  You don't have to remember everything, but you have know, where to look and search.  If you don't understand black magic like autowiring, you will always be baffeled by the things they achieve.

Comment: sadly, I have both answers knowledge, but they suffer from "if the code is perfect in all places" problem, for example, we used to call something ProviderTests, we now call them "Lab Tests" but the classes never got renamed, so if you know that...

Comment: This is technical dept.  Holster your katana and fix it.  It seems to me, that your frustration comes from a complex, ages old monolith of a codebase - and quite honest it often is.

Comment: quite possibly, I was just hoping there might be some technical solution that makes this easier. Such a solution doesn't seem impossible. I'm tempted (but probably too lazy) to dig into the thread view code and see if I can't make it a bit smarter (or something like that) Something, has to know what's currently executing.